# When can be socket client disconnected

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io, client-server

please look at the code below. It's a simple program in nodeJS. 
Question is why `disconnect` is not printed? (If you uncomment `setTimeout`, problem is gone)
What is the real question?: Why can't I start socketIO client and server together and close a socket immediately after connection? What is the know-how regarding connections with socketIO?

```
"use strict";
var Promise = require("bluebird");
var socketio = require("socket.io");
var socketio_client = require("socket.io-client");
var http = require("http");

var port = 7457;
var hostandport = "http://localhost:" + port.toString();

var server = socketio.listen(port);

var client = socketio_client(hostandport);

server.sockets.on("connect", function (socket) {
    console.log("connect");
    socket.on("disconnect", function () {
        console.log("disconnect");
    });

    //setTimeout(function() {
        client.disconnect();
    //}, 1000);
});
```

Comment: use socket.disconnect();

Comment: @OP Did you solve your problem? I haven't seen any responses such as "this worked" or "this didn't work, it gave me (error 404: example error not found)."

Answer (score 1):

You have set up your server incorrectly, do this instead:

```
var server = require('http').createServer(handler);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

io.on("connect", function (socket) {
    console.log("connect");
    socket.on("disconnect", function () {
        console.log("disconnect");
    });
//More importantly, you have done this part wrong, 
//the rest of your code may be functional, 
//but it does not adhere to what socket.io sets out in its own API
//(http://socket.io/docs/)
        socket.disconnect();
});
```

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I had this nearly all typed up, but my computer keeps crashing.

Answer (score 0):

In Socket.io there is no such thing as connection on server side and/or browser side. There is only one connection. If one of the sides closes it, then it is closed. So you can close it from Server using socket.disconnect()

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log('a user connected');
  socket.on('disconnect', function(){
    console.log('user disconnected');
  });
  setTimeout(function() {
    socket.disconnect();
  }, 1000);
});
```

Goto http://socket.io/get-started/chat/ for more clarifications.